# Importing from utility package / module on a higher level in Python 3

Tags: python, import, module, path, python-import

Given the following structure in my **python3** project:

```
.
├── utils
│   └── someutil
│       └── Stuff.py
└── tools
    └── sometool
        └── Main.py
```

Where the content of `tools.sometool.Main.py` looks like this:

```
import XXX utils.someutil.Stuff XXX
```

Where XXX means "I am clueless please help me with this import statement". Further In the structure above I want to enter the commandline:

```
python3 tools/sometool/Main.py
```

and have it execute without failing on the import. What is the best and cleanest way to do this in Python 3?

I have experimented with putting `__ini__.py` files with lots of statements like

```
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../')))
```

And the like. Is there really no better way?

Comment: `sys.path.append()` is what I follow and it has worked for me till now. I'm not sure why you're facing an issue.

Comment: Where is the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @Sraw: I have tried many combinations, but really in utills, someutl tools and sometools. Also I ajusted the ../.. to ../ depending on the level.

Comment: @LennartRolland I don't think any of them will work. As when you use `python3 tools/sometool/Main.py` to execute, the only loaded file before importing is `Main.py` itself. You will need to add that into `Main.py` or create something like `bin/helper.py` to config the path. And surely, run `python3 bin/helper.py`.